# Can jquery draggable stop get the stopped over object attribute data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

This is a jquery question for the draggable stop event.

I'm trying to get the table cell that the 'stop' occurred on.

like here:

```
 stop: function(event, ui) {

     var el = allElementsFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
     var tablecell = $(el).filter('td').not($(this));

     tablecellStartDate = tablecell.data-start;
}
```

the html is just

```
<td data-start="2014-1-25"></td>
```

In the console (FF) I get: start is not defined
and this does work:

```
tablecell.css({'backgroundColor': 'yellow'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an element attribute that way. You can use `tablecell.attr('data-start')` or `tablecell.data('start')`